# How to change a property when another property is changed in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am using WPF and MVVM for a project. I have a view with a GridView control. User can Insert/Update/Delete In Grid View. when any of the action happen changes reflect in ViewModel. This part is working Ok. But when I want to save the changes in Database I need to loop through each Item in ItemSource one by one. which takes the extra time to complete. I want to process only those Items which are changes.

To accomplish this , I add a boolean property in my Model to indicate whether the Item is changed or note. But problem is that I can not see any way to set this boolean property whenever any other property is changed.

Can any body help me how to do it?

**EDIT**
I have a SelectedItem Property , and I am assuming that whenever an Item is selected in GridView , User will update or insert the row. so on SelectedItem property I have set boolean property of SelectedItem to True. and while looping to save  records I am saving all those records who have True in their boolean property. I know its not the perfact way, but right now I do not have any other way to do it. Your thoughts?

Comment: How do you work with your database? If you use some ORM, say Entity Framework, it tracks the changes by itself so you shouldn't worry about that.

Comment: I am not using nay Entity Framework. I am using System.Data.SqlClient Classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subscribe to the PropertyChanged event on your Model and set the Flag to True.
But keep in mind that you have to set the Flag to false after you loaded the data from the database, because the initialization of the model will also call the propertychanged event.

Example for class with IsDirty-Flag:

```
public class Sample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private bool isDirty;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            if(id != value)
            {
                id = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get { return isDirty; }
        set
        {
            if (isDirty != value)
            {
                isDirty = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsDirty");
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (propertyName != "IsDirty")
        {
            IsDirty = true;
        }

        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

if you are using an ObservableCollection, you can also add an eventhandler to track the rows that are newly added or  deleted

Comment: I am not sure how to use PropertyChanged Event on my Model. Because everywhere I see people using it on ViewModel. Yes , I am using ObservableCollection, But I am not finding a way that when a property is changed?

Comment: you can use implement the INotifyPropertyChanged on your Model like you do on a ViewModel, there is no difference in the implementation. To simplify the usage of this interface I'm using NotifyPropertyWeaver (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bd351303-db8c-4771-9b22-5e51524fccd3) that injects the needed notification Code.

Comment: ObservableCollection does not notify you about changes of an item, but it notifies you if an item has been added to or removed from the collection, so you may need both, INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged

Comment: Thanks for your response , I will implement INotifyCollectionChanged and how it is different than INotifyPropertyChanged and then I will come back to you with my updates. Can you check the edit part of my question and comment on that?

Comment: I Implemented Following,  MyViewModel.CollectionChanged += MyViewModelCollectionChanged; In constructor of my view model. But I noticed that it is only working If a new Item is added in my ObservableCollection or removed from it. Not , for updated items.

Comment: yes, you need to subscribe to the PropertyChanged event of each item to get notified about updates. I have added example code for a class that sets a boolean Property ("IsDirty") to true if another property was changed.

Comment: Thanks. Its working fine. just one more think I would like to ask, I know I can give any name to IsDirty Property , but is there any specific reason that most of the tech guys are using IsDirty for this boolean property? I saw some others blogs where developers used this name.

Comment: @bittech i use IsChanged to be more compatible with the IChangeTracking interface http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ichangetracking.ischanged.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you use MVVM you should have implementation of **INotifyPropertyChanged**. And you can add some logic to set up yours boolean property in **OnPropertyChanged** handler.

Comment: Yes , I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to take a dependency on a build time tool you can do this with ILWeaving.

So if you combine [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) with the [PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) addin then IsDirty functionality is supported out of the box.

Then Martins example can be simplified to this

```
public class Sample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChanged { get; set; }
}
```

Note the use if `IsChanged` instead of `IsDirty`.

And then this will exist in the compiled assembly

```
public class Sample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            if (id != value)
            {
                id = value;
                IsChanged = true;
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

    bool isChanged;
    public bool IsChanged
    {
        get { return isChanged; }
        set
        {
            if (isChanged != value)
            {
                isChanged = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsChanged");
            }
        }
    }

    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (!string.Equals(name, value, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                name = value;
                IsChanged = true;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
}
```